# Как сменить background-image?

Tags: html5, css

Приветствую! 
Как можно сменить фон без использования скриптов? Имеем баннер с некоторыми ссылками и нужно чтобы при нажатии на флаг страны менялся background.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**[Посмотреть пример](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/eMs2K/)**

Основная идея — работа с сестринскими селекторами:

```css
/* Это для демонстрации */
body {
  background-color: #000000;
}
label,
#rus + .lang,
#eng + .lang {
  display: inline-block;
}
#rus + .lang,
#eng + .lang {
  height: 11px;
  width: 16px;
}
#rus + .lang {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/11x16/663399/663399.png);
}
#eng + .lang {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/11x16/993366/993366.png);
}
/* Прячем radiobutton. Установка состояния checked будет по клику на label. */
input[name="lang"] {
  display: none;
}
/* Выделяем флаг в зависимости от выбранной страны */
input[name="lang"]:checked + .lang {
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
#image-holder {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
/* Меняем фоновую картинку, в зависимости от выбранной страны */
#rus:checked ~ #image-holder {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/200/663399/ffffff.png);
}
#eng:checked ~ #image-holder {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/200/993366/ffffff.png);
}
```

```html
<input id="rus" type="radio" name="lang" checked="checked" />
<label class="lang" for="rus"></label>
<input id="eng" type="radio" name="lang" />
<label class="lang" for="eng"></label>
<div id="image-holder"></div>
```